# Is detach necessary when updating record?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, .net-4.5, entity-framework-6

I am working with `VS2013`, `.NET4.5`, `EF6` and `SQL 2008`.

I have noticed that one of developers in our team changed all the update statements from

```
if (!journey.WillAnswer.Any()) 
{
    db.WillAnswer.Add(willAnswer);
} 
else 
{
    db.WillAnswer.Attach(willAnswer);
    db.Entry(willAnswer).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

to

```
if (!journey.WillAnswer.Any()) 
{
    db.WillAnswer.Add(willAnswer);
} 
else 
{
    var will = db.WillAnswer.Single(x => x.Id == willAnswer.Id);

    db.Detach(will);
    db.WillAnswer.Attach(willAnswer);
    db.Entry(willAnswer).State = EntityState.Modified;
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

**Is detach necessary? Is it good practice?**

Comment: Did you ask him why he did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is certainly bad practice because now there are two `will` objects floating around in the app that have the same key. One of them is a detached "dummy" and will simply lose any writes made to it. This is error-prone and confusing.

Maybe your app is not using EF like it is supposed to be used. Normally, there is not a lot of attaching and detaching at all. EF objects are meant to be "live" objects representing the database state. They are not DTOs that you create at will and throw away. Especially avoid generic repo methods such as `MyRepository.AddOrUpdate` taking a temporary entity.

If you want to write to an entity, obtain it and write. Do not create a new entity for updating.

Comment: I thought so too, could be one of unknown unknowns. Thanks.